# Gams uncontrolled index issue

Tags: gams-math

I have this situation in GAMS:

```
Sets
         i       mina  / m1, m2 / ;

Parameters
         k(i)  non important description
         /       m1       10
                 m2       20 /;


Variables
         x(i)  non important description;

Equations
         r1    non important description;

r1 ..            x(i) =l= k(i);
```

and r1 give me the error `149  Uncontrolled set entered as constant`.

What can I do to fix it? I've searched all around but nothing makes sense, x(i) and k(i) have the same dimentions, I just want to say that x(i) <= k(i) for all i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare and define your equation differently to say, that you want it for all i and not just once. Do it like this:

```
Equations
         r1(i)    non important description;

r1(i) ..            x(i) =l= k(i);
```

Comment: Does this work for 2 variables? For example, if I have two matrices A and B with same dimension and I want to make a constraint that every `A(i,j) <= B(i,j)`, would this be right:
`Equations r2(i,j)` and `r2(i,j) .. A(i,j) =l= B(i,j)`
?

Comment: Yes, it works that way. Maybe this is interesting for you: https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_Equations.html#UG_Equations_Definition_Indexed